GLSL Voxel Raytracer Not Rendering Correctly
I've been trying to write a voxel raytracer in GLSL using A Fast Voxel Traversal Algorithim for Ray Tracing, but I can't get it working. The code should draw the voxels in VOXEL_GRID as cubes, but instead it appears to be "painting" them on the outside of the bounding box.
Current shader output as viewed from an angle:

As you can see, it looks like it is texturing the bounding box instead of drawing the voxels as cubes. Here's the relevant part of the compute shader:
const int MAX_STEP_COUNT = 128;  // Used to prevent an infinite loop, just in case.
const int GRID_WIDTH = 8;
const int GRID_HEIGHT = 8;
const int GRID_DEPTH = 1;

// "1" means the cell is full, "0" means that it's empty.
const int VOXEL_GRID[GRID_WIDTH * GRID_HEIGHT] = int[GRID_WIDTH * GRID_HEIGHT](
    0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0
);


int getSign (float value) {
    return 0 - int(uint(value) >> 31) * 2;
}

vec3 getSignOfDirection (vec3 value) {
    return vec3(getSign(value.x), getSign(value.y), getSign(value.z));
}


// Returns the distance to the bounding box, or 1e30f if it's a miss.
float rayBoxCollision (vec3 minimum, vec3 maximum,
                       vec3 rayOrigin, vec3 rayDirection) {
    float tmin = 0;
    float tmax = 1e30f;

    for (int axis = 0; axis < 3; axis += 1) {
        const float t1 = (minimum[axis] - rayOrigin[axis]) / rayDirection[axis];
        const float t2 = (maximum[axis] - rayOrigin[axis]) / rayDirection[axis];

        const float dmin = min(t1, t2);
        const float dmax = max(t1, t2);

        tmin = max(dmin, tmin);
        tmax = min(dmax, tmax);
    }

    if (tmax >= tmin) {
        // Hit.
        return tmin;
    }

    // Miss.
    return 1e30f;
}


bool doesRayHitVoxel (vec3 rayOrigin, vec3 rayDirection) {
    vec3 gridMin = vec3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    vec3 gridMax = vec3(1.0, 0.0, 1.0 / 8.0);


    float rayEntryTime = rayBoxCollision(gridMin, gridMax, rayOrigin, rayDirection);
    if (rayEntryTime == 1e30f) {
        // Miss.
        return false;
    }


    vec3 voxelsPerUnit = vec3(GRID_WIDTH / (gridMax.x - gridMin.x),
                              GRID_HEIGHT / (gridMax.y - gridMin.y),
                              GRID_DEPTH / (gridMax.z - gridMin.z));
    
    vec3 gridEntryPosition =
         vec3((rayOrigin + rayDirection * (rayEntryTime + 0.0001)) -
              gridMin) * voxelsPerUnit;
    if (gridEntryPosition.x < 0 || gridEntryPosition.x >= GRID_WIDTH ||
        gridEntryPosition.y < 0 || gridEntryPosition.y >= GRID_HEIGHT ||
        gridEntryPosition.z < 0 || gridEntryPosition.z >= GRID_DEPTH) {
        return false;
    }
    vec3 gridPosition = gridEntryPosition;

    vec3 stepDirection = getSignOfDirection(rayDirection);
    vec3 timeDelta = abs(1.0 / rayDirection);
    vec3 timeMax = (gridEntryPosition + max(stepDirection, 0)) / rayDirection;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_STEP_COUNT; i += 1) {
        int gridIndex =
            int(gridPosition.z) * GRID_DEPTH * GRID_HEIGHT + int(gridPosition.y) *    
            GRID_WIDTH + int(gridPosition.x);
        int voxel = VOXEL_GRID[gridIndex];

        if (voxel != 0) {
            return true;
        }

        if (timeMax.x < timeMax.y) {
            if (timeMax.x < timeMax.z) {
                gridPosition.x += stepDirection.x;
                if (gridPosition.x < 0 || gridPosition.x >= GRID_WIDTH) {
                    break;
                }
                timeMax.x += timeDelta.x;
            } else {
                gridPosition.z += stepDirection.z;
                if (gridPosition.z < 0 || gridPosition.z >= GRID_DEPTH) {
                    break;
                }
                timeMax.z += timeDelta.z;
            }
        } else {
            if (timeMax.y < timeMax.z) {
                gridPosition.y += stepDirection.y;
                if (gridPosition.y < 0 || gridPosition.y >= GRID_HEIGHT) {
                    break;
                }
                timeMax.y += timeDelta.y;
            } else {
                gridPosition.z += stepDirection.z;
                if (gridPosition.z < 0 || gridPosition.z >= GRID_DEPTH) {
                    break;
                }
                timeMax.z += timeDelta.z;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}


vec4 calculateRayColor (vec3 rayOrigin, vec3 rayDirection) {
    if (doesRayHitVoxel(rayOrigin, rayDirection)) {
        // Hit!
        return vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }    

    // Miss.
    return vec4(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
}

The function calculateRayColor is called per pixel, and the result is stored in a texture that is then sampled and rendered onto the screen. I've checked all the other code, and the problem seems to be in doesRayHitVoxel or in getSignOfDirection.
